# Iterating objects in es6 and returning new object

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6

Using es6 javascript is it possible to iterate over an object and return a new object. For example:

```
const people = {
    'Sally': {
        age: 22,
        sex: 'female',
    },
    'John': {
        age: 64,
        sex: 'male',
    },
    'Sam': {
        age: 12,
        sex: 'female',
    },      
};

const ages = people.someEs6IteratingObjectFunction((index, person) => {
    return { Object.keys(people)[index]: person.age };
});

console.log(ages); // { 'Sally': 22, 'John': 64, 'Sam': 12, }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method of array prototype. It also works in es5.

```js
const people = {
    'Sally': {
        age: 22,
        sex: 'female',
    },
    'John': {
        age: 64,
        sex: 'male',
    },
    'Sam': {
        age: 12,
        sex: 'female',
    },      
};

let result = Object.keys(people).reduce(function(r, name) {
  return r[name] = people[name].age, r;
}, {});

document.write(['<pre>', JSON.stringify(result, 0, 3), '</pre>'].join(''));
```

Comment: Although can you please explain what the sequence operator does. Its a little complex for novices. Let's be verbose on stackoverflow.

Comment: The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand

Comment: Yes, understood :-) although its often a rule in ESLint to disallow this. It can be confusing. Perhaps two examples?

Comment: In that case just split this expression into two parts. `r[name] = people[name].age; return r;`.  I didn't know about this rule :)

Comment: :-) thats cool, also there is a rule "do not return assignment statements".. AirBnB linting...

Answer (score 1):

One option if you're not super concerned about potential performance:

```
const ages = people.reduce(
    (obj, name) => Object.assign(obj, {[name]: obj[name].age}), {});
```

or maybe

```
const ages = Object.entries(people).reduce(
    (obj, [name, info]) => Object.assign(obj, {[name]: info.age}), {});
```

Or make an ES6 `Map` instead of using an `Object`:

```
const ages = new Map(Object.entries(people).map(
    ([name, info]) => [name, info.age])))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Object.entries` is still not standard.

Comment: @Bergi It's stage 4, officially in, just waiting for the official ES2016 spec release!

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Being in stage 4 *now* means it will be part of ES2017.

Comment: Woops, my mistake! So close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, I wish I could take credit for this, it is from Axel Rauschmayer's blog, he has several other amazing blog posts here: http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html

Here is a [JSBin with the code below:](https://jsbin.com/hujeyum/1/edit?js,console)

```
 function objectEntries(obj) {
        let index = 0;
        let propKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(obj);
        return {
            [Symbol.iterator]() {
                return this;
            },
            next() {
                if (index < propKeys.length) {
                    let key = propKeys[index];
                    index++;
                    return { value: [key, obj[key]] };
                } else {
                    return { done: true };
                }
            }
        };
    }

    let obj = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' };
    for (let [key,value] of objectEntries(obj)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
```

This is even easier if you use generators: http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/es6-generators.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's isn't an equivalent of `Array.map` for objects in ES6.

Maybe you can make a helper function to mimic this. It would iterate over your object, calling the callback for each key with the value at that key, and replacing that value with whatever the callback returns. Something like:

```
const objectMap = (obj, cb) => 
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((ppl, k) =>
    Object.assign(ppl, {
      [k]: cb(obj[k])
    }), {}
  );
```

And then use it like:

```
const newPeople = objectMap(people, val => val.age);
console.log(newPeople); // Object {Sally: 22, John: 64, Sam: 12}
```

Running example:

```js
const people = {
  'Sally': {
    age: 22,
    sex: 'female',
  },
  'John': {
    age: 64,
    sex: 'male',
  },
  'Sam': {
    age: 12,
    sex: 'female',
  },
};

const objectMap = (obj, cb) => 
  Object
  .keys(obj)
  .reduce(
    (ppl, k) =>
    Object.assign(ppl, {
      [k]: cb(obj[k])
    }), {}
  );

const newPeople = objectMap(people, val => val.age);

console.log('---- People ----');
console.dir(people);

console.log('---- New People ---- ');
console.dir(newPeople);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `for...of`?

```
 const people = { 'Sally': { age: 22, sex: 'female', }, 'John': { age: 64, sex: 'male', }, 'Sam': { age: 12, sex: 'female', },
};

const ages = {};
for(let index of people) {
  ages[key] = people[key].age;
}
console.log(ages); // { 'Sally': 22, 'John': 64, 'Sam': 12, }
```

Comment: Standard objects aren't iterable so for..of won't work.